# ¿"Darse de alta a xxxx" o "Darse de alta en xxxxx"?

Tags: preposiciones

Cual es la forma correcta para decir las frases "darse de alta en Facebook", o "darse de alta al grupo de discusión". ¿Hay alguna regla de uso?

Answer (score 6):

*Darse de alta* equivale a *inscribirse* y lleva la misma preposición: **en**. Sospecho que el uso de **a** se debe a una confusión con la palabra *suscribirse*, con la que sí rige dicha proposición y que a veces también puede actuar como sinónimo de las anteriores:

- Me he inscrito en el grupo de discusión
- Me he dado de alta en el grupo de discusión
- Me he suscrito al grupo de discusión

Answer (score 0):

Sin duda:

> Darse de alta **en** un curso / un grupo / Facebook / la Seguridad Social ...

El uso de la preposición **a** en este caso es erróneo.